# is it allowed in REST to have consecutive resource Ids

Tags: rest

Is it allowed as per REST standard to have consecutive ids in the URI like

```
/something/something/something/{resourceId1}/{resourceId2}
```

I didn't find anything specific in REST documentation as far as I investigated, and I cant imagine a case for this (using correct notion of resource Ids as per REST standards, and not as an absolute place holder)

Comment: As noted--it's not a standard. If they identify the same **type** of resource, e.g., retrieving two users by their ID, I'd say it's very counter-intuitive. If it's a nested resource it's counter-intuitive because the second resource isn't named. If it's two IDs required to identify a single resource it's counter-intuitive because they're not IDs anymore *(only when they're smushed together)*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no REST standard. It is an architectural style, not a specification. Your URLs should uniquely identity a resource; if your URLs need two numeric segments to do this, that's fine.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say, if something is an object(i.e. user) you want to access in that case you should pass only one id in the URL parameter at the end.

`/user/[id]`

In case you want to access multiple resources of the same object then pass those ids in the query parameter

`/user?ids=id1,id2,id3...id10`

Comment: This doesn't attempt to actually answer the question that was asked.